# Arguments to raylib function have incorrect texture, not able to borrow a reference

Tags: rust, raylib

```
use raylib::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let (mut rl, thread) = raylib::init().size(640, 480).title("Hello, World").build();

    while !rl.window_should_close() {
        let mut d = rl.begin_drawing(&thread);

        d.load_texture(&d, "./assets/Grass.png"); // error here
        d.clear_background(Color::BLACK);
    }
}
```

> mismatched types expected reference `&RaylibThread`    found reference
> `&RaylibDrawHandle<'_>`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
> main.rs(12, 11): arguments to this function are incorrect
> texture.rs(856, 12): associated function defined here

I figure i borrow the reference by doing `&d` Maybe im missing something. I'm a bit confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The [`load_texture`](https://docs.rs/raylib/3.7.0/raylib/core/struct.RaylibHandle.html#method.load_texture) function expects a reference to a [`RaylibThread`](https://docs.rs/raylib/3.7.0/raylib/core/struct.RaylibThread.html) as first argument, but you are passing in a reference to a [`RaylibDrawHandle`](https://docs.rs/raylib/3.7.0/raylib/core/drawing/struct.RaylibDrawHandle.html).

Therefore you will need to change the line with the error to:

```rust
d.load_texture(&thread, "./assets/Grass.png");
```

Comment: this makes sense, but i get this 

```cannot borrow data in dereference of `RaylibDrawHandle<'_>` as mutable
trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `RaylibDrawHandle<'_>```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the answer i was able to resolve the issue, i guess i had to move this line before the while loop

```
use raylib::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let (mut rl, thread) = raylib::init().size(640, 480).title("Hello, World").build();
    let texture = rl.load_texture(&thread, "./assets/Grass.png");
    texture.unwrap();
    while !rl.window_should_close() {
        let mut d = rl.begin_drawing(&thread);

        d.clear_background(Color::BLACK);
    }
}
```